# UBSan And Asan usage with GCC 4.9.2

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior, address-sanitizer, ubsan

I have compiled my application with `-fsanitize=undefined` option. How can I now test my application for undefined behavior?

Also, how do I run an Asan check? I've compiled my program with `-fsanitize=address`, and it crashes with the following output:

```
==4563==Sanitizer CHECK failed: ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:85 ((allocated < kCallocPoolSize)) != (0) (0, 0)
```

I've got GCC 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: The asan issue as my updated answer says looks like a bug but I could not find a specific one that exactly matches. Your best bet is probably to file a bug report with a specific test case. If you could specify the test case that it fails on in the question it would be more helpful.

Comment: *"How can I now test my application for undefined behavior?"* - Asan and UBsan operate on real data. You test your application by running its self tests. If you are following [GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/), then `make check` is your next step.

Comment: Also, @shafik provides an important option for UBsan, `-fno-sanitize-recover`. It is very useful when testing someone else's program when they use a test framework. Often time test frameworks swallow all messages and pretty print OK. That means you miss UBsan's output *`runtime error: ...`*.  `-fno-sanitize-recover` causes an `abort()` so the messages are not lost to the test framework.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike a static analysis check, this check will be done at run-time as explained in the following blog entry: [GCC Undefined Behavior Sanitizer – ubsan](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan). It will output a runtime error when it detects undefined behavior:

> In order to check your program with ubsan, compile and link the
> program with -fsanitize=undefined option. Such instrumented binaries
> have to be executed; if ubsan detects any problem, it outputs a
> “runtime error:” message, and in most cases continues executing the
> program. There is a possibility of  making these diagnostic messages
> abort — just use the option -fno-sanitize-recover.

And we can see an example from there:

```
int main() {
    int i = 23;
    i <<= 32; 
}
```

when ran using `-fsanitize=undefined`  will output (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ebd9831fb6cd311)*):

> runtime error: shift exponent 32 is too large for 32-bit type 'int'

GCC documents this option in their [Options for Debugging Your Program or GCC section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and it says:

> Enable UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer, a fast undefined behavior detector.
> Various computations are instrumented to detect undefined behavior at
> runtime.

As for the asan issue this [address-sanitizer document](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) gives you an example and the expected results. Perhaps your case it related to [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59733).

Comment: This sample works fine, but if my application is concerned, UBSan outputs nothing. Also, I somewhy have to force link it (-lubsan) for my app, while it is not needed for your sample...

Comment: @Ilya have you tried inserting code that has known undefined behavior such as the sample above to see if at least that is flagged? If not, it sounds like a distribution issue or an install issue but that starts getting far away from the original question of *How can I now test my application for undefined behavior?*. A quick scan online comes up with nothing obvious.

Comment: Well, I have found a way of successful compilation without -lubsan. Now I use -fsanitize=undefined on linking, not on compilation. However, even obvious problems aren't reported (like int i=23; i <<= 32;). My app has a GUI; may this be a problem?

Comment: @Ilya: If you don't *compile* with `-fsanitize=undefined`, no calls to libubsan functions appear in the compiler output, so it links fine if you omit `-lubsan`.  But of course then it's not doing any sanitizing.  Maybe your sample worked without `-lubsan` because there were no places where it inserted runtime UB checks.